# How to delete files from Backup data On azure Backup

Tags: azure, backup

I have Azure backup installed on my PCs and by mistake selected the wrong folder for Backup which is very large (around 50GB).

How to delete that data from the Azure backup (Stored in the cloud).

I can not find a way to delete that files from the cloud.

Backup for File and Folders on Win 10 PC. Yes in Recovery Services Vault. I do not want to delete entire vault, but one folder only.

Comment: Can you provider more details about your backup?In the Recovery service vault ? What's the backup for ? Azure VM? This document may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-delete-vault

Comment: I just edited my post with the information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently, you can’t delete individual recovery point/Backed-up data from the recovery services vault; recovery point/Backed-up data deletes automatically if it reaches the retention period. if you choose to delete your backup data while stopping the protection, it will delete all the recovery points/Backed-up data associated with the item.

Refer the below article to exclude file/folder from Backup:

[Manage exclusion settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-manage-windows-server#manage-exclusion-settings)